# Magento PWA - How do I get Tier price in product details page to show?

Tags: magento2, product, tierprice, pwa, pwa-studio

I am working with **PWA studio**. And I want to show **tier price** list in product details page. But I am not getting how I can get them in product page. Does anyone have any idea how to bring that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the tier price of products, you can use the following GraphQl query.

```
query {
  products(filter: { sku: { eq: "PRODUCT-SKU" } }) {
    items {
      price_tiers {
        discount {
          amount_off
          percent_off
        }
        final_price {
          value
          currency
        }
        quantity
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Learn more about what product information can be obtained using a GraphQl query.](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/schema/products/queries/products/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how can I save a custom customer attribute data in PWA?